# How to solve that complicated equation with parameter?

Tags: equation-solving

[image]

I try to solve for "t" at the various "x"  from the function of

```
f[t_, x_] = 
  0.5 Erfc[(x - 0.0236454911650369 t)/Sqrt[4*0.0108274976811351*t]] + 
   0.5 Exp[0.0236454911650369 x/0.0108274976811351]*
    Erfc[(x + 0.0236454911650369 t)/Sqrt[4*0.0108274976811351*t]];

Table[{x, t /. NSolve[{f[t, x] == 0.05}, t, Reals ][[1]]}, {x, 0.5, 
  10, 0.5}]
```

and get coordinates as (x,t). But it does not work as shown in the picture. Please give me any advise on how to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: You may plot the function using ContourPlot

Comment: Try `Table[{x, t /. FindRoot[f[t, x] - 0.05,{t, 0.5}]}, {x, 0.5, 1, 0.05}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give provide a range interval instead of a domain restriction, than [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve) will work as desired:

```
Table[{x, t /. NSolve[f[t, x] == 0.05 && 0<t<10^6, t][[1]]}, {x, 0.5, 10, 0.5}]
```

> {{0.5, 2.44177}, {1., 8.28915}, {1.5, 16.2759}, {2., 25.7474}, {2.5, 
>     36.3187}, {3., 47.7426}, {3.5, 59.8506}, {4., 72.5218}, {4.5, 85.6665}, {5.,
>      99.2161}, {5.5, 113.117}, {6., 127.325}, {6.5, 141.806}, {7., 
>     156.531}, {7.5, 171.476}, {8., 186.619}, {8.5, 201.944}, {9., 
>     217.435}, {9.5, 233.079}, {10., 248.864}}

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the best method,

Answer (score 2):

`ContourPlot` shows you possible solutions `x,t`

```
ContourPlot[f[t, x] == .05, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 5},FrameLabel -> {x, t}]
```

[image]

The solutions can be calculated using `NMinimize`

```
sol[x_?NumericQ] := {x, t /. #[[2]], #[[1]] } &[NMinimize[{(f[t, x] - 0.05)^2, 0 < t < 5}, t]]
```

(don't know why `solt[x_?NumericQ]:=t /. NSolve[{f[t, x] == 0.05, 5 > t > 0}, t, Reals][[1, 1]]` doesn't work for the whole range of t)

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea. But it can't apply with my whole range of x ( eg. x = 0.5 to 500)

Comment: In your  question you mention a range of `0<x<10` ???

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. Here is your equation:

```
eq = 0.5 Erfc[(x - 0.02*t)/Sqrt[4*0.01*t]] + 
   0.5 Exp[2*x]*Erfc[(x + 0.02*t)/Sqrt[4*0.01*t]] == 0.05
```

I think you do not really need all that precision, therefore, I shortened all numbers. Let us draw it:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{0.05, 0.5 Erfc[(x - 0.02*t)/Sqrt[4*0.01*t]] + 
    0.5 Exp[2*x]*Erfc[(x + 0.02*t)/Sqrt[4*0.01*t]]}, {t, 2, 310}], {x, 0.5, 10}]
```

yielding the following:

[image]

which shows that as x varies between 0.5 and 10 the solution for t runs from about 2 to about 310. 
Let us now solve the equation and make a list `lst` of solutions with the element `{x,t}`:

```
lst = Table[{x, FindRoot[eq, {t, 300/9.5*x}][[1, 2]]}, {x, 0.5, 10, 0.1}];
```

One can now have a look at the solutions

```
ListPlot[lst, AxesLabel -> {Style["x", Italic, 16], Style["t", Italic, 16]}]
```

with the effect

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea. But it can't apply with my whole range of x ( eg. x = 0.5 to 500)

Comment: @Ron  I used the limits for x from your question. If you need other limits they should be specified. Generally, I do not see, why this method should not work for x=500. The only thing is that you will need to use different initial guesses there. Probably, the initial guess, 300/9.5*x, that I invented is not good at large x values. If this is the case, you might either invent another expression, or divide the whole interval into pieces 0.5 to 500 and find a solution for each piece separately and then combine them. Anyway, my task is to introduce you an idea. All the rest is your business.